# rabbitMQ cluster setup

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, installation

I am setting up rabbitMQ cluster on 2 nodes -- node1, node2.  and try to make node2 to join node1's cluster

what I did is following :
1, install rabbitMQ (and Erlang) seperately on node1 and node2, 
2, "rabbitmqctl stop_app" on node2,  delete the  .erlang.cookie and then copied  .erlang.cookie from node1 to node2
3,  "rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@node1",   now I have connection error, "unable to connect to node rabbit@node2",  cookie issue.

if I copy back the old .erlang.cookie  generated by node2,  I will have connection error to  rabbit@node1,  (which make sense, since I am supposed to copy node1's cookie to node2).

anything I am doing wrong here...

Thanks

Comment: are the nodes reachable by name?

Comment: yes. But I noticed that rabbitMQ clustering should only be used for machines in one location,  which is not in my case.  I am looking at rabbitMQ Federation, the problem with Federation is that it has direction.   What I need is clustering with machines in different locations

Answer (score 2):

In case you install the nodes on different machines you must make sure the machines are reachable.

in Linux:
1) update /etc/hosts 
on slave:

on master:

2) open tcp ports 1-20000 (or 1-65535)  between the nodes
   This is usually the problem!

good luck!